# Bar is selected for click on empty area. How to avoid to highlight on bar for clicking empty space?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Bar is selected when we click on empty space above the each bar. Here I need to avoid highlight on bar for clicking empty space.

[image]

Comment: What and where is the question?

Comment: Here I need to avoid highlight on bar for clicking empty space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to prevent bars from being highlighted when clicking on empty space above them.

The only thing you could do is **reduce the empty space above the bar**.

Comment: Hi Philipp, 
Is it possible to prevent in upcoming releases?

Comment: any solutions of this problem  as of now??